# Usage as the prime language directive

Tags: word-usage

I once studied Old English in college and remember a reference to a Scottish minister who said that the language was essentially strictly driven by usage.  Now in my very senior years I cannot recall his name.  Does anyone recall who the minister was?

Comment: Whoever he was, he was right. And he wasn't the first by any means; this is standard doctrine in linguistics: language is oral, and language changes are changes in usage. Period.

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scottish_linguists) may jog your memory (three Scottish linguists listed here are claimed to have been ministers), but  queries purely about sources are rarely on-topic on ELU.

Comment: A strong suspect must be James_Burnett, Lord Monboddo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Burnett,_Lord_Monboddo *In* The Origin and Progress of Language *Burnett analysed the structure of languages, and argued that humans had evolved language skills in response to changing environment and social structures.* But he was not a "minister" but could have been a Doctor of Laws.